# Build AWS SDK Jar to Import for a Single Package

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jar

I would like to use the Java AWS SDK only for S3 at the moment.
So, instead of importing the entire AWS SDK jar file I wanted to only import the necessary packages for accessing my S3 bucket into my web application (IDE: Netbeans).

To do this, I read that I should use Maven to build the jar I need.

I have tried two approaches but can't seem to also include all of the aws-java-sdk-s3 dependencies in the jar that I am building.

**First approach**

1) I download the zipped aws-sdk-java folder from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java

2) I unzip to a local folder.

3) I navigate to the aws-java-sdk-s3 (ie: where the pom is located) folder in my console, then type "mvn clean install".

While this builds a jar file (located in `aws-java-sdk-s3/target`), the jar does not contain the dependencies specified in the POM file (eg: it does not include the BasicAWSCredentials class in the core package which I need).

**Second Approach**
Change the POM file located in the aws-java-sdk-master folder so that it imports the BOM and specifying my requirement (S3) by adding:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.67</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and removing all other dependencies listed in the POM (eg: junit).

This approach fails while building the DynamoDB package, which I don't even need it to be building (I want to specify that it only needs S3).

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?
Perhaps the main issue here is that I'm new to Maven.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what version of SDK you are using. You should be just able to import s3 module only - http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.10.67/ also check the AWS guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-using-maven.html

Comment: Thanks. The s3 jar that you link to doesn't include `core` classes (I was under the impression that it should because the `core` package is a dependency of `s3` but maybe I'm misunderstanding something)...I am familiar with the second link you provide, I couldn't get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

update your pom.xml properly likewise,

```
<dependencies>

....


<!-- AWS dependencies -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.43</version>
</dependency>

....

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Jar that you are interested directly from maven : 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.10.66/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.66.jar

update the URL with the version of the sdk you want to use and you can just import the jar in your project, no need to rebuild it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also making use of the BasicAWSCredentials class, which is part of the `aws-java-sdk-core` package. This package is listed as a dependency but for some reason the BasicAWSCredentials class is not included in the jar that you link to. I can always just download the `core` jar as well...I'm just wondering if it shouldn't all be packaged in one jar?

Comment: right from the link you will only get the s3 class, it will not contain the dependencies; if you're using them you would need to download separately and upload in your project

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood what a dependency was. I figured that since AmazonS3Client can accept a BasicAWSCredential Object as a parameter then that would mean that the BasicAWSCredential is considered a dependency and would by included in the jar. I guess that only the classes necessary to build the package are the ones that are considered dependencies? Is this correcy?

Comment: that is dependency management - when you use a 3rd party lib you do not package it with your jar file, you will define a dependency so that for a tool which will resolve dependency (maven, gradle) they will download your tool + the correct lib

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me using Gradle. Here is the Gradle build file I used as advised by the [API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html).

```
group 'aws.test'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
      mavenBom 'software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.0.0-preview-12'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```